# function posted to boost::asio::io_service::strand not executed

Tags: boost, boost-asio, deadlock

I am using `boost::asio` in a quite complex scenario and I am experiencing a problem where a method posted to a `boost::asio::io_service::strand` object is not executed although several worker threads on the `io_service` are running and idle.

As I said, the scenario is very complex, I'm still trying to develop a reasonably small repro scenario. But the conditions are as follows:

- one io_service is running and has a work-object assigned to it
- 4 worker threads are assigned to the io_service (called `io_service::run` on each)
- several strand objects are used to post numerous different tasks
- in some of the tasks that are executed via the strands, new tasks are posted to the strand

The whole system works well and stable, except for one situation:
When calling the destructor of one of the classes, it posts the abort handler to the strand  (to initiate aborting in sync with the other taks) and then waits until abort is done.
Every once in a while it now happens, that the abort handler is never executed (destructor is called from an invocation of another strand object).

I assume the problem is that the strand waits for executing the handler on the same thread that it has been posted. And since this thread is waiting for the abort handler to be executed the program deadlocks.

My questions now: 
 - is my assumption correct? 
 - is there any way to avoid this situation? 
 - how would you approach that problem (having several async tasks running and need to abort them synchronously)

Thanx a lot for your help!

m.

Comment: Your assumption is correct. The only workaround I found in such a situation was to launch a temporary thread explicitly and to move the blocking code to it. Of course, this would require some re-design, because your "waiting" code should also be moved to that thread (perhaps, it can be just passed as a lambda/nullary functor).

Comment: Thanx for your reply. In the meantime I found a way to modify the workflow so that the blocking call is not necessary at that point. Anyway, I'll need to fix that problem some time soon and then I'll try out your suggestions.